# How to change turn-by-turn navigation voice language in Google Maps for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, navigation

I have my iPhone's language set to English in Settings, but I live in a non-English speaking country. As such, when using turn-by-turn navigation, street names are pronounced as though they were English words, and are barely recognizable.

Is there a way to get Google Maps' navigation feature to speak my language without changing the systemwide language setting?

Comment: an alternative answer for you but the waze app have such setting

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since iOS 13, you can now change each application's default language, and that is possible for Google Maps too, by going to `Settings > Google Maps > Preferred Language` (at the very bottom of that screen). You should be able to select one from the multiple languages you have installed on the iPhone (by default, of course, Google Maps will use the iPhone's 'standard' language).

If you don't see any other language there (besides the 'standard' one, i.e. the one the iPhone is displaying everywhere), then you can add more languages by going to `Settings > General > Language & Region > Other Languages...` and add there all the languages you wish; then go back to `Settings > Google Maps > Preferred Language` and the new language(s) should be available for selection!

Source: https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/change-languages-per-app-basis-your-iphone-ios-13-0208770/ (last accessed 2019-11-22)

Comment: Note: in my case (using Portuguese), very few messages are actually *spoken* out loud (e.g. 'turn left'), I just get the 'attention sound'; but this seems to be a restriction of Google Maps on the iPhone app, since even changing the main iPhone language to Portuguese (and not only the language for Google Maps) will not make a difference. Still, *some* messages are clearly spoken in Portuguese and not in English... I'm a bit baffled at that.

Comment: "...add there all the languages you wish;" except Български. 

Comment: Huh. Somehow, it feels weird to search on Google for an answer to this question, follow the links and the step-by-step instructions, noting that it actually still works correctly, hitting the 'upvote' link and getting an error message saying that 'You cannot vote on your own post'. Riiight. I guess I got dumber in just two years.
Anyway, I just wished to add to my own answer that, these days, a few _more_ messages are spoken in Portuguese (at least, 'turn left/right' works); however, Google still refuses to pronounce the names of the streets... also, the voice they picked is _very_ annoying!

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately, Google Maps doesn't have Language controls built into the app. It cues off of the settings in Settings.app > General > International.

The only way to have Google Maps speak a different language is to change the actual settings in Settings.app > General > International > Language.

Of course, this doesn't take long to change, and it may be desirable to change it before using turn-by-turn for perhaps a long trip.

It would be a good idea to request that feature from Google by opening the Google Maps app and tapping the person icon in the upper right corner. Then tap "Send Feedback" and compose a request to Google.

### Minor Update

You can now set voice search language in the app. There is a mic icon on the right in the search box that you can tap to basically dictate the location. While that doesn't apply to your question, perhaps that would be a first, mildly helpful step.

Answer (score -1):

You can now set the voice language without changing the system language.

[image]

Comment: That screenshot is from Android and I don't have that option on Google Maps on my iPhone?

Comment: Indeed, the OP asked for how to do that change in iOS, not Android...

Answer (score -2):

I changed the phone language settings and it is the easiest fix, and will help you improve your Spanish, or you could try a different GPS app

Comment: Note that the OP clearly stated that they do *not* wish to change the iPhone's language, neither change to a different app; also, 'helping improve your Spanish' only applies if *a)* the OP is navigating in a Spanish-speaking country; or *b)* they're actually *interested* in improving their Spanish — which they certainly did *not* specify in the question...